# Reformatting data in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

have something kinda weird here. I have a database that's called FLDOC. In it has a column called SENTENCE that contains 7 numbers that represent a length of time.

```
example:
0050000
0750000
0000600
0040615
0000110
```

In those 7 digits is a length of type since the digits represent YYYMMDD

So what I'd like is a script that can convert it to something like this:

```
5Y 00M 00D
75Y 00M 00D
6M (or 000Y 6M 00D is fine as well)
4Y 6M 15D  etc etc
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CONCAT` is new to SQL Server 2012. If you have previous version of SQL Server, you could do something like this instead to achieve your desired output:

```
SELECT sentence
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN cast(left(sentence, 3) AS INT) > 0
                THEN cast(cast(left(sentence, 3) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'Y '
            ELSE cast(left(sentence, 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'Y '
            END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN cast(substring(sentence, 4, 2) AS INT) > 0
                THEN cast(cast(substring(sentence, 4, 2) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'M '
            ELSE cast(substring(sentence, 4, 2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'M '
            END + 
         CASE 
            WHEN cast(right(sentence, 2) AS INT) > 0
                THEN cast(cast(right(sentence, 2) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'D'
            ELSE cast(right(sentence, 2) AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'D'
            END
        ) AS new_sentence
FROM FLDOC;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70aa9/7/0)

**UPDATE**

To answer your question below in the comments, you could maybe just write a update statement like this:

```
update FLDOC 
set sentence = (
        CASE 
            WHEN cast(left(sentence, 3) AS INT) > 0
                THEN cast(cast(left(sentence, 3) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'Y '
            ELSE cast(left(sentence, 3) AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'Y '
            END + 
        CASE 
            WHEN cast(substring(sentence, 4, 2) AS INT) > 0
                THEN cast(cast(substring(sentence, 4, 2) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'M '
            ELSE cast(substring(sentence, 4, 2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'M '
            END + 
         CASE 
            WHEN cast(right(sentence, 2) AS INT) > 0
                THEN cast(cast(right(sentence, 2) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'D'
            ELSE cast(right(sentence, 2) AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'D'
            END
        )
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you as I am on 2008 and 2012 as well

Comment: umm.. how would I turn that into an update command? Looks great in preview pane but need it to update the table.

Comment: @Sal Please check my update answer above. I believe it should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select convert(varchar(10),left(example,3))+'Y '+
convert(varchar(10),Substring(example,4,3))+'M '+
convert(varchar(10),Right(example,3))+'D'+ from tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `Concat` as well:

```
Select  Concat
        (
            Left(SENTENCE, 3), 'Y ', 
            SubString(SENTENCE, 4, 2), 'M ', 
            Right(SENTENCE, 2), 'D'
        )
From    Table
```

To condense the expression as in your example, this can be used as well:

```
Select  Concat
        (
            Case When (IsNumeric(Left(SENTENCE, 3)) = 1 And Left(SENTENCE, 3) <> '000')
            Then Convert(Varchar (3), Convert(Int, Left(SENTENCE, 3))) + 'Y ' End,

            Case When (IsNumeric(SubString(SENTENCE, 4, 2)) = 1 And SubString(SENTENCE, 4, 2) <> '00')
            Then Convert(Varchar (2), Convert(Int, SubString(SENTENCE, 4, 2))) + 'M ' End, 

            Case When (IsNumeric(Right(SENTENCE, 2)) = 1 And Right(SENTENCE, 2) <> '00')
            Then Convert(Varchar (2), Convert(Int, Right(SENTENCE, 2))) + 'D' End
        )
From    Table
```